# Package pst-bar displays multi-line ref incorrect with breaklinks enabled

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, pstricks

I've got a long document and while wrapping things up I noticed a strange bug in my document after compilation with Latex -> dvips-> ps2pdf

The following packages are used throughout my document

- *pst-bar*: for bar charts and similar throughout my document, and
- *breaklinks* + *hyperref*: in my bibliography and for some other lists.
- *tocloft*: for a *newlistof* (see below)

Now, I've created a *newlistof* but if the title of an entry is too long for one line the ref will be placed somewhere between the lines of the title and hence isn't really clickable. This seems to be caused by *pst-bar* but removing this package or *breaklinks* would mean a lot of rewriting for me. Does someone here know a fix without removing any of the packages? A minimal working example is attached:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}          

  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
  \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

  \usepackage{mathtools}    
  \usepackage{pst-bar}  
  \usepackage{tocloft}  

  \usepackage[pdftoolbar=true,
            pdfmenubar=true,
            pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
            bookmarksnumbered=true,
            colorlinks=false,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
  \usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}

  %***** Create List of Algorithms ************************
  \newcommand{\newtempdima}{9em}    % width of tag column in list of algorithms
  \newcommand{\dummytitletext}{List of Dummys}

  \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\newnumberline}[1]{%
        \hb@xt@\newtempdima{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
    \newcommand{\listdummy}{\dummytitletext}
    \newlistof{dummys}{dum}{\listdummy}
    \renewcommand{\cftdummysnumwidth}{\newtempdima}
  \makeatother

  \newcommand{\dummy}[2]{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{dum}{dummys}{\protect\newnumberline{#1}#2}}
   %***** End: Create List of Algorithms ************************
\begin{document}

    \listofdummys

    \bigskip

    \section*{Text}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.


    \begin{align} \label{alg:CSLP-ast} \dummy{$(CSLP^\ast)$}{Short Description} 
            (CKSLP^\ast) ~ 
            \min \
                    & \sum_{i \in N} {\frac{1}{n_i} \ f_{i} \ y_{i}}    
                    & y_{S^{Depot}}= 1  \\
                    &   e_{ic} \leq E
                    & \forall  (i,c) \in N^1    \\
                    & e_{S^{Start},c+1} = e_{S_{Term},c}
    \end{align}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam non.

    \begin{align} \label{alg:CSLP-T} \dummy{$(CSLP-T)$}{Overlong Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing e}
        (CKSLP-T) ~
        \min \
            & \sum_{i \in N} \sum_{t \in T} \sum_{b \in B}^{f^{bat}_b z_b} x \cdot \beta    \\
            & \sum_{t \in T} y_{S^{Depot},t} = 1    \\
            &   e_{ic} \leq \sum_{b \in B}{E_b \cdot z_b}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, I was trying to find a way defining the width of the tag column automatically, e.g. largest width of all tags defined. It, of course, works by defining the width at some sufficiently large fixed value and although I'm satisfied with that (as nothing large will change in my document) it would be nice knowing the right way to solve this issue. I tried, for example, removing the box in *\newnumberline* but this results in a bad indent for the second line.

Would really appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load the package `hypdvips`after `hyperref`. According to its manual, `hypdvips` offers 'support for breaking links' and fixes problems when using `hyperref` with `dvips`.

As an alternative, you could also use `hyperref`'s option `linktocpage=true`. With this option enabled, the clickable hyperlinks in the lists and the toc are the page numbers rather than section titles or figure captions.

EDIT: Usage of `hypdvips` in combination with `natbib`: 
To use `hypdvips` together wih `natbib`, you could write the following lines into your preamble (after loading `hyperref`):

```
        \usepackage{hypdvips}
        \makeatletter
        \renewcommand{\Hy@backout}[1]{}
        \makeatother
```

In the MWE I used to test, this eliminates the errors and correctly prints the citations. However, I am not sure, if this will work in all setups, so the 'safest' solution might be the alternative I have suggested above or switching to a different compiler as suggested by Herbert.

Comment: Using hypdvips solves the stated problem. However, I'm additionally using natbib and adding hypdvips results in the error that e.g. citep is undefined and other errors from the natbib package. Any idea?

Comment: @Martin: I have added a workaround, that eliminated the problem, at least in the MWE I used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xelatex` instead of the sequence with `latex` works. There
are only a few changes in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}          
\usepackage{fontspec}      
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{pst-bar}  
\usepackage{mathtools}    
\usepackage{tocloft}  
\usepackage{setspace}  

%***** Create List of Algorithms ************************
\newcommand{\newtempdima}{9em}    % width of tag column in list of algorithms
\newcommand{\dummytitletext}{List of Dummys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newnumberline}[1]{%
    \hb@xt@\newtempdima{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
\newcommand{\listdummy}{\dummytitletext}
\newlistof{dummys}{dum}{\listdummy}
\renewcommand{\cftdummysnumwidth}{\newtempdima}
\makeatother

\usepackage[pdftoolbar=true,
pdfmenubar=true,
pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
colorlinks=false,
breaklinks=true,
urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\dummy}[2]{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{dum}{dummys}{\protect\newnumberline{#1}#2}}
%***** End: Create List of Algorithms ************************
\begin{document}

{\setstretch{1.2}
\listofdummys}

    \bigskip

    \section*{Text}
[...]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works fine. However, leandriis' suggestion with hypdvips doesn't require changing engine, but you're right using xelatex from start would have been simpler